# Proof of homotopy invariance of homology : any way to make it better?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Suppose you want to prove that homotopic maps induce the same morphisms in singular homology. One way to do that is the following : you have your homotopy $X\times I \to Y$, apply $Sing$ to it to get $Sing(X)\times Sing(I)\to Sing(Y)$, and then you have a natural map $\Delta^1\to Sing(I)$ which yields $Sing(X)\times \Delta^1\to Sing(Y)$, and since homology only depends on $Sing$, it's clear that it suffices to prove the following :

let $X\times\Delta^1\to Y$ be a simplicial homotopy, then the two maps $X\to Y$ induce the same map in simplicial homology.

To do that, it's again clear that it suffices to show that $X\to X\times \Delta^1$ is a homology isomorphism. One possible method of proof is to build the beginning of simplicial homotopy theory (but some purely formal bits) as follows :

1- Show it has the lifting property against Kan fibrations, by essentially proving the pushout product axiom; for that it suffices to check that for all $n$, $\partial \Delta^n \times \Delta^1\cup_{\partial \Delta^n \times \{0\}} \Delta^n\times \{0\}\to \Delta^n\times \Delta^1$ has the given lifting property. This can be done by hand, by expressing the given map as a composition of pushouts of horn inclusions.

2- Conclude by the small object argument that $X\to X\times \Delta^1$ is a retract of a cell-complex (built on $\Lambda^n_k\to \Delta^n$'s)

3- Prove that "induces an isomorphism on homology" is stable under retracts and pushouts and transfinite compositions.

4- Prove that $\Lambda^n_k$ and $\Delta^n$ both have zero homology.

Of these steps, only 1 and 4 have some "non conceptual" content, they contain some computations (for 1, you need to express explicitely the map as a pushout of horn inclusions, so you need to find those inclusions; for 4 you need to actually compute some homology, albeit quite simple)

But it seems to me that you can do this more quickly, by actually expressing directly $X\to X\times \Delta^1$ as some relative complex of horn inclusions, if that's possible; since this sort of computation is there anyways, if you can do it, you might as well bypass the whole argument.

So my first question is :

> Is there an explicit construction of $X\to X\times \Delta^1$ as obtained by pushouts and transfinite compositions (and maybe a retraction) of horn inclusions $\Lambda^n_k \to \Delta^n$ ?

My second question is about the proof I sketched above, specifically about the computational points I noted :

> Is there a way to bypass the computations ? More specifically, 1- is there a way to prove that  $\partial \Delta^n \times \Delta^1\cup_{\partial \Delta^n \times \{0\}} \Delta^n\times \{0\}\to \Delta^n\times \Delta^1$ has the left lifting property against Kan fibrations without having to find out which horn inclusions do the right thing ? and 2- is there a way to prove that $\Lambda^n_k\to \Delta^n$ is a homology isomorphism without computing both homologies and discovering that they are $0$ ?

(note that for all these questions, the point is to avoid using powerful stuff, because the end goal is to prove some basic property : the homotopy invariance of homology; so of course I can't accept "well $|\Delta^n|$ is contractible and simplicial homology coincides with singular homology so $H_*(\Delta^n) = 0$" as that would help in no way what I'm trying to do)

Comment: You can write out an explicit description of the boundary between the images of cycles. Are you trying to avoid this?

Comment: @ConnorMalin something like the prism operator ? If so, yes, I'm trying to avoid the prism operator in a sense, I'm trying to reduce things to combinatorics

Comment: But the prism operator is coming directly from the combinatorial description of $\Delta^n \times I$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin : of course, but I'm trying to make things more explicitly combinatorial. And actually there's also a purely psychological thing where I don't like the usual proof with the prism operator and so I'm trying to avoid it somehow (so find a different proof)

Comment: I’ll add that you can similarly show that the homology of $\Delta^n $ is trivial by just observing you can cone off any cycle to show it is a boundary.

Comment: @ConnorMalin : what do you mean, "cone off" ?

Comment: The proof of homology really doesn’t need any prism operator. You can also simplify it by just considering the maps $X \rightarrow X \times I$ including at the bottom and top. It literally is almost instant from seeing the decomposition of the product.

Comment: An example is that the sum of all the faces except $[0,\dots,n]$ cones off $\partial[0,\dots, n]$ in the n+1 simplex.

Comment: Massey's book on Singular Homology uses a cun=bical

Comment: Massey's classic book on Singular Homology uses a cubical rather than simplicial approach, which has several advantages - one is the equation $I^m \times I^n \cong I^{m+n}$, which makes dealing with homotopies much simpler, See also a paper in HHA by Patchkoria  using cubical sets with connections for a theory of derived functors, which is actually used in aspects of motivic homotopy theory, in preference to the simplicial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an answer to my specific questions, but I just thought that if the end goal is proving that $X\to X\times \Delta^1$ is a homology isomorphism, there's a much quicker way, although perhaps less formal, through Dold-Kan.

Indeed, $\mathbb Z[X\times \Delta^1]\cong \mathbb Z[X]\otimes \mathbb Z[\Delta^1]$ (here $\otimes$ is dimensionwise), and the Dold-Kan correspondance is monoidal, so $C_*(X\times\Delta^1;\mathbb Z)\simeq C_*(X;\mathbb Z)\otimes C_*(\Delta^1;\mathbb Z)$, where now $\otimes$ is the usual chain complex tensor-product.

So we're reduced to computing $C_*(\Delta^1;\mathbb Z)$ up to homotopy (note that $C_*(X;\mathbb Z)$ is a complex of projectives, so $C_*(X;\mathbb Z)\otimes- $ preserves quasi-isomorphisms), but by Dold-Kan this is entirely explicit, and one easily checks $C_*(\Delta^1;\mathbb Z)\simeq \mathbb Z$ (in degree $0$), from which the result immediately follows.