# Homology is homotopy invariant, fake proof with simplicial methods?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Here is a maybe false proof that I came up with that homology of topological spaces is homotopy invariant. I'm thinking that it is indeed fake because why hasn't anyone else come up with this much simpler proof until now if it was correct?

$\textbf{Proof}:$

Let $\text{Sing}(-)$ denote the singular set functor $\textbf{Top} \rightarrow s\textbf{Set}$ then if two maps between topological spaces $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ are homotopic by $H:X \times \Delta^1_{Top} \rightarrow Y$ where $\Delta^1_{Top}$ is the 1-simplex as a topological space.

Then $f_{\#},g_{\#}:\text{Sing}(X) \rightarrow \text{Sing}(Y)$ are homotopic by the simplicial homotopy $$\text{Sing}(X) \times \Delta^1 \xrightarrow{id \times \phi} \text{Sing}(X) \times \text{Sing}(\Delta^1_{Top}) \xrightarrow{H_{\#}} \text{Sing}(Y)$$
where $\phi: \Delta^1 \rightarrow \text{Sing}(\Delta^1_{Top})$ is the obvious map and $\text{Sing}(X) \times \text{Sing}(\Delta^1_{Top}) = \text{Sing}(X \times \Delta^1_{Top})$.

And since simplicial homology is homotopy invariant $f_*=g_*:H_*(X) \rightarrow H_*(Y)$

$\textbf{Finished}$

The classic proof of homotopy invariance of the homology functor relies on the acyclicity of the $\Delta^n_{Top}$ w.r.t the homology functor, something which isn't used here. That's what leads me to believe that this is indeed false. I haven't been able to spot the error yet though.

Also, the map $\phi$ is explicitly the unit of the adjunction $\mid -\mid \dashv \text{Sing}(-)$, that is if $\eta: \text{id} \rightarrow \text{Sing}(\mid - \mid)$ then $\eta_{\Delta^1} = \phi$

Thanks for helping me out in advance!

Comment: Initial thought:  you use the fact that simplicial homology is homotopy invariant.  Is proving that on its own any easier than the traditional tactic for singular homology?

Comment: Well, of course if you know that homology is homotopy invariant for simplicial sets it follows immediately for singular homology since it factors through the singular complex functor. This just moves the key part towards simplicial sets instead of topological spaces. It might be technically simpler, but I guess most basic textbooks would consider it more advanced. It's also a more "modern" point of view (well not exactly brand new but more recent than the most classical proofs).

Comment: How do you prove homotopy invariance of simplicial homotopy ? Your question is related to mine (here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504257/proof-of-homotopy-invariance-of-homology-any-way-to-make-it-better) where I sketch a purely simplicial proof of the homotopy invariance of simplicial homology (it's all reduced to two combinatorics questions : proving that $H_*(\Delta^n) = H_*(\Lambda^n_k) = 0$ and proving that a certain monomorphism is actually anodyne)

Comment: @Max You can do it using the acyclic model theorem relatively easily.

Comment: @CaptainLama so my proof is correct?